# Batch script to remove "duplicate" files

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of files named:

> ```
> file.txt
> file (1).txt
> file (2).txt
> ```
>
> etc.

Where the greater (number) is the last file updated.

I want a `.bat` script that allows get the content of `file (maxnumer).txt` to `file.txt`.

Comment: What did you tried as code ?

Comment: i have no idea how to do it. i now how to use for loops, if conditions, set variables, but i don't have much experience. Mi first idea would be to run a for loop and test if "file (%i).tex" exists. But then i'm not sure how to proceed...

Comment: I cannot find a question in your post. The title says you want to remove something, but the "question" body does not describe what to remove, it only says someting about copying a file onto another. So please clarify! Does the file with the greatest number also have the latest creation or modification date? Then share what you have tried so far and what you have problems with! StackOverflow is not the place to ask for scripts for free! Read this: [ask]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dir /B /OD /TW file*.txt` lists file names in sort order of last written time (cf. `dir /?`).

Next commented batch script could do the job for you:

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
rem delete empty `_lastfile` variable
set "_lastfile="
rem store file name of last written time into `_lastfile` variable
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B /OD /TW file*.txt 2^>NUL') do set "_lastfile=%%~G"
rem                                                ↑↑↑↑↑↑ suppress errors
rem check the `_lastfile` variable
rem is defined?
rem                  AND is different from "file.txt"?
if defined _lastfile if /I "%_lastfile%" NEQ "file.txt" copy /Y "%_lastfile%" "file.txt"
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`2>NUL` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of a hacky answer.

This script will move all files from `file (1).txt` up to `file (10).txt` to file.txt , leaving only file.txt which now contains the text that was in file (10).txt

Doing it in ascending order will ensure the highest number that exists is the last one to be moved.

```
@echo off
set /P name=Enter name of file without extension: 
echo enter extension:
set /P ext=.
echo. & echo.
echo these actions will be performed: & echo.
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,10) DO @echo move /y "%name% (%%A).%ext%" "%name%.%ext%"
echo. & pause & echo.
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,10) DO       move /y "%name% (%%A).%ext%" "%name%.%ext%"
pause
```

You could use `IF EXIST %name% (%%A).%ext%` To stop the script from trying to move files that don't exist, but it doesn't really affect anything to do that, so I didn't bother.

The script above will do it for a specific named file.  To do it for all files in a directory will be possible, here are some hints to get you going

use a `dir /b >filenames.txt` to get all files in a directory listed in a text file

to perform an action for every line in a textfile do

```
for /f "usebackq delims= tokens=* %%a in (`filenames.txt`)" DO (
    ::some stuff here
)
```

The way I would go about it would be to get filenames.txt , manually delete all the (n) files so you just have a list of the "non-duplicate" filenames, and use that as your input.  You

There are probably more elegant solutions out there, but with all the peculiarities of batch I wouldn't be surprised to find they are pages and pages long.

If you want to keep all the original files not just end up with the final file.txt with no copies, then I you want to use COPY

If you want to keep all the original files, then you would want to use COPY not MOVE.

In that case, to remove all superfluous operations (i.e. only copy the highest numbered file, not copy all the files in order) then something like `IF NOT EXIST %name% (!B!).%ext%`  where `!B!=%%A+1` within your (now multiline) for loop and use Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion on to make the arithmetic work properly.  But it's not really necessary, copying 1, then 2, then 3, then 4 does the same thing if a little slower than skipping 1 2 and 3 and just doing 4.

I hope this helps enough to point you in the right direction, feel free to ask questions if this isn't clear.